# Swift Syntax Meaning "public class Signal<T> { }"

Tags: swift

I am seeing codes like below:

```
public class Signal<T> { 
 ...
}
```

what does `<T>` mean?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what's known as a [Generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming). It means that the Signal class can operate on multiple types. For instance, you could instantiate an object of type `Signal<String>`, or perhaps of `Signal<Foo>`, or any other type.

Generics allow the same code to work with lots of different types of data, and still retain type safety.